# Load local css file inside event listener function

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code that uses a remote github repository to load a css file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

$.ajax({

url: 'www.websitehere.css',

success: function(css) {

$("<style></style>").appendTo('head').html(css);

}

});
```

To prevent constant loading from a remote repository that I do not own I want to load my own css file. I've make a file called mytheme.css that I have saved in the same folder as my js file and tried to call it using the code below.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

$.ajax({

// url: 'www.websitehere.css',

success: function(css) {

    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="mytheme.css" type="text/css" />');

}

});
```

However, this does not work, is there a way to load a local css file inside an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem as me, here's the answer:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var fs = require('fs'),
  filePath = '/foo/bar/baz/mytheme.css';

  fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      var css = document.createElement('style')
      css.innerText = data;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
    }
  })
```